# Real-time threat finder

Tags: anti-virus, cloud, real-time

I want to make a small program that is capable to download files from the cloud onto my system. As the file reaches my system, another program on my system will analyze the file and try to find suspicious behaviors in it.

I want to make a system similar to ThreatExpert (www.threatexpert.com). The suspicious data gathered by my program will be sent to Anti-Virus companies for analysis.

I want to know whether this program can be written in .NET or as a PHP website. I have no experience of Cloud computing. How to retrieve files from the cloud?

Comment: "Cloud" just doesn't mean anything. Basically it's the Internet. If by "cloud", you mean some kind of "distributed storage", you usually download files like any other file, by HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part of this could be done with MITRE's honeyclient project (http://www.honeyclient.org/trac) and/or captureBAT (https://www.honeynet.org/node/315), however you may need some custom scripts to select and download files.  Honeyclient is intended to find websites that exploit your system, while captureBAT is a behavioural analysis tool to help characterize software.  This would be run in a VM, running one program at a time, and then the log files would need to be studied to determine if the behaviour of the software is actually malicious.

Answer (score 0):

What does "The Cloud" mean in this case?

In general, the answer is that you'd use HTTP as the transport. It's quite good at the task of sending a request and getting a file back.

Comment: Is there any source from where files can be collected for analysis?

Comment: What files do you want? Are you just looking for random files, or do you have something particular in mind?

Comment: Which files do you want to collect?

Comment: I think he actually wants to download sample virus code or something. This question makes me twitch.

Comment: I don't want sample virus code to spread. Just visit the site www.threatexpert.com. What it is doing? It is collecting malwares in real-time.

I want to test the heuristics of modern AVs and also I want to write my own program to detect malwares in real-time. If found, my program will automatically submit suspicious files to AV companies.

Comment: Right - so the logical question for me to ask at this point is "Where do you plan to source your files?", except you've already asked us where you should source your files, so it's clear you have no idea.